# Breeze returning very large amount of text for anonymous type in custom query

Tags: breeze

I'm not sure that I'm really helping Breeze much with my query, but I'm returning approx 1500 records to use in a treeview plugin that needs to be filterable. I'm creating a custom query to do this in order that my post-processing to create the tree nodes is as efficient as possible.

As I'm cherry-picking fields for my query, I understand that Breeze will not be able to identify each record as a specific type so maybe there's some way I can define a view or class that Breeze can access that will define my returned record and cut down on overhead?

Currently 1500 lots of:

```
$type: "VB$AnonymousType_3`8[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Int32, mscorlib],[System.Boolean, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib]], PKL2"`
```

is adding quite a lot of overhead!

My query:

```
    Dim matquery = (From g In dc.Groups
                    Where g.IncludeInTree = True
    Select New With {
        .key = "f_" + CStr(g.Id),
        .title = g.GroupDesc,
        .isFolder = 1,
        .isCompetitor = False,
        .g1 = g.Group1,
        .g2 = g.Group2,
        .g3 = g.Group3,
        .g4 = g.Group4
    }).Union(From av In dc.ArticleVersions
                 Join g2 In dc.Groups On g2.Id Equals av.GroupId
                    Where av.IsDeleted = False
    Select New With {
        .key = "a_" + CStr(av.ID),
        .title = av.ArticleCode,
        .isFolder = 0,
        .isCompetitor = av.IsCompetitorArticle,
        .g1 = g2.Group1,
        .g2 = g2.Group2,
        .g3 = g2.Group3,
        .g4 = g2.Group4
    }).OrderBy(Function(x) x.g1).ThenBy(Function(x) x.g2).ThenBy(Function(x) x.g3).ThenBy(Function(x) x.g4).ThenByDescending(Function(x) x.isFolder).ThenBy(Function(x) x.title)
    Return matquery
```

...and a sample of returned data:

```
{
$id: "1093",
$type: "VB$AnonymousType_3`8[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Int32, mscorlib],[System.Boolean, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib]], PKL2",
key: "a_1100",
title: "V31-607356",
isFolder: 0,
isCompetitor: false,
g1: "2",
g2: "25",
g3: "255",
g4: "2551"
},
{
$id: "1094",
$type: "VB$AnonymousType_3`8[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Int32, mscorlib],[System.Boolean, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib]], PKL2",
key: "a_1101",
title: "V31-607361",
isFolder: 0,
isCompetitor: false,
g1: "2",
g2: "25",
g3: "255",
g4: "2551"
},
{
$id: "1095",
$type: "VB$AnonymousType_3`8[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Int32, mscorlib],[System.Boolean, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib]], PKL2",
key: "f_268",
title: "Cups, plastic, printed",
isFolder: 1,
isCompetitor: false,
g1: "2",
g2: "25",
g3: "255",
g4: "2552"

}, ...
```

The returned type is currently an anonymous/custom type but I'm happy to create a class/view if that will help breeze?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is, yes I can!

Adding:

```
Public Class treeItem
    Public key As String
    Public title As String
    Public isFolder As Boolean
    Public isCompetitor As Boolean
    Public g1 As String
    Public g2 As String
    Public g3 As String
    Public g4 As String
End Class
```

to my code and changing the select to `Select New treeitem With {...` instantly changed the return to:

```
$type: "PDK2.treeItem, PKL2"
```

...and more than halved the data size returned